# Windows 7 or Windows Vista in the cloud

Tags: windows, cloud-computing, cloud-hosting

Hi I am looking for a cloud-based solution that offers Windows 7, Windows Vista, or Windows XP to be served in the cloud using VNC or a similar remote desktop.  Does such an offering exist?

Is there a licensing solution from Microsoft?

Answer (score 3):

Your search terms for this should be something like "Virtualized Desktop Cloud Provider" or "Desktop as a service" (DaaS)

Here are a few:

- http://www.desktone.com/
- http://virtuon-inc.com
- http://www.enomaly.com/Cloud-Desktops.459.0.html

Answer (score 1):

VMware View and VMware ACE

Comment: Reread the question and my comment.

Comment: I assumed you could search for providers offering those products as a service and you didn't ask for a Microsoft-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Citrix is a common solution, but it runs on Windows Server, not Windows Client.

Comment: I am looking for a service like EC2 or Rackspace Cloud.  There are many providers that offer Windows Server.